# Setting up a cloud server

Tags: server, cloud

I want to set up a certain distro of ubuntu as a server, the server will have to handle 500 at most users. Where do I go for such a service? I tried AWS and Azure - but they just confuse me with their product offerings.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello @Nat, your question is very broad. On StackOverflow you have to show what analysis you have done and if you have some doubts on some specific service offering, so such questions you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe host it on your own? If that's not the Answer, Google is providing an service similar to AWS which is in my opinion much more cleaner.. try this!